# .PDF icon corrupted on Windows 7

Tags: icons, windows-7

If I double click on the .PDF, files I can open them with Foxit PDF reader, but the icon is wrong (I have the icon of the unknown files). How I can fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try rebuilding the Windows 7 icon cache.

- Open up a Command Prompt (`Start -> cmd`)
- Run:

  ```
  del /ah "C:\users\YOUR_USERNAME_HERE\appdata\local\iconcache.db"
  ```
- Reboot

Comment: didn't work. any other ideas?

Comment: Try going into properties then where it says `Opens with:` choose foxit again and hit apply. Does the foxit program have the right icon under Program Files? Maybe try reinstalling foxit?

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution to this problem. I am running Windows 7 64-bit and using the 32-bit Foxit Phantom software.

When the program is installed, the default registry entry for the program icon in:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\FoxitPhantom.Document\DefaultIcon
```

is:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\foxit software\foxit phantom\Foxit Phantom.exe"
```

Apparently Windows 7 64-bit needs the additional icon reference number if an icon is stored in an .exe (as in this case) or other icon containing files. The correct value for the registry key to correctly display Foxit Icons is:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\foxit software\foxit phantom\Foxit Phantom.exe,-128".
```

After saving and rebooting, the correct icon should be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, however it turned out the icons weren't actually the icons of unknown files but thumbnails of the first pages of the documents (PDF and other).

To make it show normal icons:

1. open Windows Explorer and click on Organize → Folder and Search Options
2. go to the View tab and check the "Always show icons, never thumbnails" option
3. click OK

Answer (score 0):

TO make it easier, use xnview context menu to convert a downloaded png foxit icon to ico and put it in the  FoxIt Reader folder. you'll notice in the folder that Foxit Reader.exe doesn't have an icon either. Right click on the exe file, go to Properties, choose Change Ico, direct it to the ico file you just put there and that's it. No registry tampering.

Answer (score 0):

i ended up combining the registry fix with an icon file i made from an image i found online (i made the alpha channel from scratch though ;)

here's the link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7nQ3z6WmzIjVGlrblRob2llbkU/view?usp=sharing

so ya, download that icon, and throw it into your foxit Program Files folder (for me that was **C:\Program Files (x86)\Foxit Software\Foxit Reader**) and then point this regkey to it:

(type **regedit** in the start search box to run regedit)
**HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\FoxitReader.Document\DefaultIcon**

so for me, that means i made the value of that key = **C:\Program Files (x86)\Foxit Software\Foxit Reader\foxitfile.ico** (or put whatever you chose to name the icon file).

after that you may need to clear your **IconCache.db**:
http://www.winability.com/repair-windows-desktop-icon-cache/

voila. it may be an inelegant solution, but it got the job done for me.